# How to add a new value by accessing another object if it exists

Tags: python

I am thinking about this question.
How could I add a new value to this object without getting an error?

```
data = {
  'attributes': processed_data['attributes'],
  'categories': processed_data['categories'],
  'filters': processed_data['filters'],
  'min_price': processed_data['min_price'],
  'max_price': processed_data['max_price'],
  'session_id': processed_data['session_id'],
  'new_value': process_data['new_value'],  # this value will not always exist
  'client_id': session.clientId
}
```

in javascript I would use the ternary operator
but I don't know how I could proceed in python

Comment: It's a `dict`.  So, just use the normal syntax:  `data[key] = value`.

Comment: not related to the question itself, but bear in mind that comments in python start with `#` and you miss a comma in `new_value` line.

Answer (score 0):

If statement:

```py
if 'new_value' in process_data:
    data['new_value'] = process_data['new_value']
```

Ternary operator:

```py
data['new_value'] = process_data['new_value'] if 'test' in process_data else -1
```

[.get()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp) Function (best):

```py
# second argument is the default if it doesn't exist
data['new_value'] = process_data.get('new_value', -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to make the dict with all the guaranteed values first, then have `if` statements afterward to optionally add more stuff.

```
mydict = {
    'key1': value1,
    'key2': value2,
    'key3': value3
}

if some_condition:
    mydict['key4'] = value4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get` method (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20get#dict.get).

```py
'new_value': process_data.get('new_value')
```

This will check if `process_data` has a key `new_value`. If not, it will set `data['new_value']` to `None` without raising a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do this since this is a dictionary:

```
data['new_value'] = your_value_here
```

And just do if condition to check whether value exists or not!

Answer (score 0):

the get() method returns the value of the item with the specified key and you can set a value to return if the specified key does not exist (default value is None)

```
car = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}

x = car.get("price", 15000)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).